# Running a command line command with PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu, command-line

So my problem is the following: I have an R markdown file on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 server that I want to be knitted via command line (this works fine with `Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('path/to/file.Rmd')"`), so I tried to run this from PHP with the **exec()** command (obviously using escape characters). The output from PHP is the following:
`Execution haltedArray ( [0] => Error: unexpected input in "rmarkdown::render(\" [1] => Execution halted )`
when running the following lines of PHP:

```
exec("Rscript -e \"rmarkdown::render(\'path/to/file.Rmd\')\" 2>&1", $output);
print_r($output);
```

What is the unexpected input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't escape the inner `'`'s

`exec("Rscript -e \"rmarkdown::render('path/to/file.Rmd')\" 2>&1", $output);`

.. or change the outermost string characters to use single quotes instead of double:

`exec('Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render(\'path/to/file.Rmd\')" 2>&1', $output);`

.. dont escape both unless you use both, which is ugly and confusing

`exec("Rscript -e \"rmarkdown::render(\\\"path/to/file.Rmd\\\")\" 2>&1", $output);`

Comment: Why is this answer correct? Why wasn't the original version with escaped double quotes inside double quotes working?

Comment: @RedBassett thanks for edit, i rushed to post, was editing but you did it

Comment: np, glad it helped.. ruddy quotes will get ya every time